# Mean of a grouped-by pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I need to calculate the mean per day of the colums duration and km for the 
rows with value ==1 and values = 0.

```
df
Out[20]: 
                          Date duration km   value
0   2015-03-28 09:07:00.800001    0      0    0
1   2015-03-28 09:36:01.819998    1      2    1
2   2015-03-30 09:36:06.839997    1      3    1 
3   2015-03-30 09:37:27.659997    nan    5    0 
4   2015-04-22 09:51:40.440003    3      7    0
5   2015-04-23 10:15:25.080002    0      nan  1
```

how can I modify this solution in order to have the means duration_value0, duration_value1, km_value0 and km_value1?

```
df = df.set_index('Date').groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='d')).mean().dropna(how='all')
print (df)
            duration   km
Date                     
2015-03-28       0.5  1.0
2015-03-30       1.5  4.0
2015-04-22       3.0  7.0
2015-04-23       0.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking pivot table i.e

```
df.pivot_table(values=['duration','km'],columns=['value'],index=df['Date'].dt.date,aggfunc='mean')
```

Output:

```
           duration        km     
value             0    1    0    1
Date                              
2015-03-28      0.0  1.0  0.0  2.0
2015-03-30      NaN  1.0  5.0  3.0
2015-04-22      3.0  NaN  7.0  NaN
2015-04-23      NaN  0.0  NaN  NaN
In [24]:
```

If you want the new column names like distance0,distance1 ... You can use list comprehension i.e if you store the pivot table in `ndf`

```
ndf.columns = [i[0]+str(i[1]) for i in ndf.columns]
```

Output:

```
            duration0  duration1  km0  km1
Date                                      
2015-03-28        0.0        1.0  0.0  2.0
2015-03-30        NaN        1.0  5.0  3.0
2015-04-22        3.0        NaN  7.0  NaN
2015-04-23        NaN        0.0  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Hi, I figured out that sometime the values in the column 'value' are all 0 or all 1.. in these particular case sI would like to have still the mean of the duration and km for both the 0 and 1 cases...(of course if the values in value are all 0 the mean for the case == 1 will be 0)

Comment: Hi, how could I change the aggregation window (in this case .dt.date) and set it for example to 1 hour?  Is it possible with your approach to use pd.Grouper(freq=freq_aggregation) being freq_aggregation the desired frequency?

Comment: @gabboshow I added the my answer for your new question.

Answer (score 2):

I believe doing a group by `Date` as well as `value` should do it. 
Call `dfGroupBy.mean` followed by `df.reset_index` to get your desired output:

```
In [713]: df.set_index('Date')\
           .groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='d'), 'value'])\
           .mean().reset_index(1, drop=True)
Out[713]: 
            duration   km
Date                     
2015-03-28       0.0  0.0
2015-03-28       1.0  2.0
2015-03-30       NaN  5.0
2015-03-30       1.0  3.0
2015-04-22       3.0  7.0
2015-04-23       0.0  NaN
```

Comment: Great answer. I have another idea I may or may not post later.

Comment: @piRSquared Thank you :) Does it involve setting a multi index and stacking?

Comment: Thanks! however I would like to keep the date as index and have 4 means columns without the value column

Comment: Followed by unstack

Comment: @gabboshow How does it look? But I think Bharath has me beat this time.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Hi, I was looking again at your answer because I think that is more flexible... for the last 2 days I get only 1 value.. how do I get if it is for "value==0" or "value==1"?
Should the output be:
2015-04-22       3.0  7.0  
2015-04-22       NaN  NaN
2015-04-23       NaN  NaN
2015-04-23       0.0  NaN